# Map is empty after finish iterate loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I need only after finish iterate loop then print map's key count.

```
 import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sample/model/GazStation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sample/util/util.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

Future<GazStation> getNearestGazStation() async {
    List<GazStation> gazStationList = await getGazStationList();
    Position myPosition = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    Map<double, GazStation> map = new HashMap();
    gazStationList.forEach((gazStation) {
      _getDistanceMetersToGazStation(myPosition, gazStation).then((distanceInMeters) {
        _logger.d("put_key = ${distanceInMeters}");
        map.putIfAbsent(distanceInMeters, () => gazStation);
      });
    });
    _logger.d("map_keys_count = ${map.keys.length}");
    return null;
  }

  Future<double> _getDistanceMetersToGazStation(Position myPosition, GazStation gazStation) async {
    var distance = Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        myPosition.latitude,
        double.parse(gazStation.Latitude),
        myPosition.longitude,
        double.parse(gazStation.Longitude));
    return distance;
  }
```

But in log first print:

```
 map_keys_count = 0
```

and after print  many times

```
put_key = xxx
```

Comment: You don't await your futures. If you don't wait for your methods to finish, then you will have no results...

Comment: @nvoigt they have used `.then(` so it should be same as `await`ing right?

Comment: @dev-aentgs No, `then` and `await` do two very different things. The first says what should happen when it's done, the other is actually *waiting* till it's done.

Comment: @nvoigt thank you.

Comment: @nvoigt `await` does not "wait" in the sense of blocking; `await` just sets up a `.then` callback automatically (and `.catchError` and `.whenComplete` callbacks if `await`ed in a `try` block with `catch` or `finally` blocks respectively).

Comment: @jamesdlin I'm aware of it. Still `await X; Y; Z;` is not the same as `X.then(Y); Z;` which was assumed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill you map correctly, you have to `await` your futures properly. However, filling a map and then returning null anyway is probably not what this method should do. This looks more like it could be what you are looking for:

```
Future<GazStation> getNearestGazStation() async {
    final gazStationList = await getGazStationList();
    final myPosition = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    GazStation closest = null;
    double closestDistance = double.maxFinite;

    for(var gazStation in gazStationList) {
      final distanceInMeters = await _getDistanceMetersToGazStation(myPosition, gazStation);

      if(distanceInMeters < closestDistance) {
         closestDistance = distanceInMeters;
         closest = gazStation;
      }
    }
    
    return closest;
  }
```

Comment: I get error:  Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods.
      final distanceInMeters = await _getDistanceMetersToGazStation(myPosition, gazStation);

Comment: Sorry I used "foreach". But after change to "for(var gazStation in gazStationList)" the problem is gone. Thanks.